# Creating my own Lists and Maps data structures

Tags: java, language-agnostic

For practice I want to make my own lists and maps (like ArrayList, HashMap, HashSet etc.).

My goal is to have it as small and flexible as possible while still maintaining good performance. (long road...)

I have some questions:

1)

Unlike the sun, I don't have to take backwards compatibility into account.
So the first thing I wonder, is there any good reason to keep `add` and `put`?
Why not just one?
If I would name `put` > `add` would this give problems / complexity / unclearness down the road?

2)

Are there any languages known to have really good data structures? (For example, they could be really smart to avoid a concurrency exception).

3)

As last more a request then a question, if you have any tips our vision of how things could be done different then please post them.

Comment: 1. Yes, there is: they're completely different operations with different parameters and return type. 2. Yes, Java for example. 3. I'd probably read the source code of the several high performance maps already existing for Java.

Comment: For variety, you could look at source code for other languages: C++ has most/all of the structures you are looking at.  It might be a useful learning exercise to do what your propose, but it is doubtful if you can do better than the existing libraries, unless you have a **very** specific application in mind.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no duplicated methods, [`Collection`'s have `add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) method that returns a `boolean`, [`Map`'s have `put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) method that returns type associated to Map.
2. There are plenty of examples of data structure, the point is, ¿what you need your data stucture do best? Avoid concurrency? sort? be fast? store securely?
3. The examples you need are directly in Java source code:

**SOURCES**

[`List`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/List.java)
[`ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java)
[`HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java)

and so on....